# VARCHAR text is not equal to Char text while comparing with LIKE operator in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have following code and it returns false for `"@B LIKE @A"` comparison in last statement.

I want to know that why Like is behaving in this way because as per my knowledge Like does the comparison on based of text not based upon data type.

```
DECLARE @Var1 Char(20)
DECLARE @Var2 VarChar(20)

SET @Var1 = 'X'
SET @Var2 = 'X'

SELECT 
@Var1 AS A,
@Var2 AS B,
LEN(@Var1) AS 'A Length',
LEN(@Var2) AS 'B Length',
CASE WHEN @Var1 = @Var2 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'A = B',
CASE WHEN @Var1 LIKE @Var2 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'A LIKE B',
CASE WHEN @Var2 LIKE @Var1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'B LIKE A'
```

Comment: Have you read the Remarks section in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)?

Comment: yes, I have read but It does n't fully clarify the things.

Comment: In SQL Server they are different. In Sybase ASE they are Equal :P

Comment: @Romil `char` means your value is padded with spaces up to the specified length. So `@Var1` ends up holding `'X<19 spaces>'`. With that in mind, read Remarks again.

Comment: GSerg, I got the answer from your comments. +1 for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@A is of type CHAR(20), so it's value is padded on the right with spaces to fill it out to a length of 20.

The Len() function excludes trailing spaces, so both @A and @B show a length of 1 even though @A has been padded out with spaces.

For comparisons, SQL Server follows ansi standards which require padding of strings to the same length before comparing, so @A and @B show as equal.

The one exception to this is the LIKE predicate, which does not pad the strings to the same length if the trailing spaces are on the right.

[Ref: How SQL Server Compares Strings with Trailing Spaces](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626)

Answer (score 2):

The CHAR value contains trailing spaces, even though you do not see them and LEN() does not report them.

Try this to verify:

```
DECLARE @Var1A Char(40) 
DECLARE @Var2A VarChar(40) 

SELECT @Var1A = @Var1 + 'x', @Var2A = @Var2 + 'x'

SELECT LEN(@Var1A), LEN(@Var2A), '"' + @Var1A + '"', '"' + @Var2A + '"'

21  2   "X                   x                   "  "Xx"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
DECLARE @Var1 Char(20)
DECLARE @Var2 VarChar(20) 
 SET @Var1 = 'X' 
 SET @Var2 = 'X' 
  SELECT  
  @Var1 AS A,
   @Var2 AS B, 
   LEN(@Var1) AS 'A Length', 
   LEN(@Var2) AS 'B Length', 
   DataLength(@Var1) AS 'A DataLength', 
   DataLength(@Var2) AS 'B DataLength', 
   CASE WHEN @Var1 = @Var2 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'A = B', 
   CASE WHEN ltrim(rtrim(@Var1)) LIKE ltrim(rtrim(@Var2)) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'A LIKE B', 
   CASE WHEN ltrim(rtrim(@Var2)) LIKE ltrim(rtrim(@Var1)) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'B LIKE A'
```